# Output HTML using existing PHP in wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

I am using the below to send an email to a user each time a custom field within their profile is updated. I can output plain text into the email body using the $message line which is great. How can I adapt this so I can output html where the $message goes?

```
// IF CUSTOM FIELD CHANGES
function sr_user_profile_update_virtuosity( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
  $old_user_data = get_transient( 'sr_old_user_data_' . $user_id );
  $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
  if($old_user_data->virtuosity != $user->virtuosity) {
    $admin_email = $user->user_email;
    $message = sprintf( __( 'I want to output HTML here' ) ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    wp_mail( $admin_email, sprintf( __( 'IMPORTANT: Your newly purchased product is ready for you' ), get_option('blogname') ), $message );
  }
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'sr_user_profile_update_virtuosity', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: so what's the problem? sprintf() outputs any text you want it to. `sprintf('<html><body>%s</body></html>', 'hi mom!')`

Comment: Oh, that's not what happened it just output the code as plain text. I'll try again later...

Comment: Hi @MarcB that still hasn't worked, it still outputs the code in play text. Any ideas?

Comment: Side-note: you might want to use `PHP_EOL` instead of `"\r\n"`....

Comment: @cale_b: php_eol is kinda pointless unless you know what the target viewing environment has the same eol character as the system running the script. e.g. php_eol on a windows box is \r\n, which is useless if the produced text will be consumed on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the content type to html, by default its `text/plain`.

You can do this by using `wp_mail_content_type` filter.

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_content_type' );
function set_content_type( $content_type ) {
    return 'text/html';
}
```

For more info see [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_content_type).

Comment: Copy the relevant code here.  Links break, and future visitors won't have a valuable answer to refer to.